# How can I make a cell that has a sum formula already in it, show 1% if the results are =/less than 0?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a formula set to show me the SUM of 2 cells(we'll say F10 & F21).

How would I make that cell showing the results of `F10+F26` reflect `1%` if the answer is less than or equal to `0`?

So if `F10-F26=-13 / F10-F26=0`, how would I make it show 1% rather than those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MAX():

```
=MAX(F10-F26,.01)
```

Now if it is less than `.01` it will return `.01` or `1%`

Comment: Would i put this after my sum formula, like this:     =SUM(F21,F10)*MAX(F10-F26,.01)        Or does the max forumla already add the 2 cells together?

Comment: the max does the math.  If you want to use sum: `=MAX(SUM(F21,F10),.01)`

Comment: Oh my goodness gracious thank you so much!!! I've been watching dang youtube videos and plowing through blogs for hours lol. Thank you so so much!!!

Comment: @ChelsieTurner  ,,, make a thumb rule,, and try to spend at least 30 minutes everyday either at Super User or Satck Overflow,, you will come across many useful solutions ☺☺

Comment: @ScottCraner If the SUM was dividing the cells rather than adding them, and if I wanted 0 to appear in the cell rather than 1, would I use this formula =MAX(SUM(CC11/CB11),0)

Comment: no need for the SUM():  `=MAX(CC11/CB11,0)` this will put 0 in for any negative return.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much you're amazing!! And i hope you checked up paypal for any Coke Zero donations lol. Thanks again!!

Comment: @ScottCraner Just one more question lol. What if i want 0 to show instead of #DIV/0!?

Comment: `=IFERROR(MAX(CC11/CB11,0),0)` @ChelsieTurner

Comment: @ScottCraner What would i do without you lol. Thank you again!!